# Help Debugging a Bogus Proof

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms, fake-proofs

We want to prove the standard fact that a smooth function $u :R^2 \to R$ with $ \nabla u = 0$ everywhere in some connected open set $ \Omega $ is constant in that set.

I'm comfortable with the usual proof, but I also thought it could be proved the following way:

$$ \nabla u = 0 \space\iff\space du = 0$$

$u$ also satisfies Laplace's equation($\nabla \cdot\nabla u = 0$), and hence has the mean value property.

Let $x_0$ be any point of $ \Omega $(distinct from the origin!). For any disk $\Delta$ about $x_0$ of radius $r$ sufficiently small, $$u(x_o) = \frac {1} {2\pi} \int_{\partial\Delta}u\space d\theta $$

But, by Stokes' theorem $$ \int_{\partial\Delta}u \space d \theta = \iint_{\Delta}du\wedge d \theta = 0 \tag1$$ (as $d^2 = 0$, and $du = 0$).

This is not the correct conclusion, as $u$ could be equal to any constant.

I think $(1)$ must be the problematic line, but I can't see why, as $$ d(u \space d\theta) = du\wedge d\theta - u \wedge d^2 \theta $$.

Comment: Well, at least one problem is you can't apply Stokes' theorem like that, because $\theta$ is not a differentiable function.

Answer (score 1):

The form $d\theta$ is not defined at $0$ (and, indeed, can't be continued across $0$), so Stokes' theorem doesn't apply. For example, Stokes' theorem would give
\begin{align*}
\int_{\partial \Delta} d\theta = \int_{\Delta} d(d\theta) = 0,\;\;\;\;\;(!)
\end{align*}
although the first integral is clearly $2\pi$. The best you can do in this situation removing a small disk around $x_0$ in $\Delta$; Stokes' theorem will then apply, although the result isn't particularly enlightening. For a deeper explanation about why this problem is unavoidable and actually more of a feature than a bug, see (for example) de Rham cohomology.

Comment: I am still confused as to what the problem is if our disk around $x_0$ is chosen so as to avoid the origin. Then your above calculation is the expected result, as the variation of argument around a cicle not containing 0 is null(or just by appealing to closed-ness)

Comment: Your form is actually $z \to d\theta(z - x_0)$; it's the argument of $z$ relative to $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the differential form $d\theta$. In Cartesian coordinates this so-called "form" is
$$
d\theta = \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}
$$
This is not a well-defined form as it is not well-defined at $x=y=0$. Another way of seeing this is if $d\theta$ was a well-defined form then $\oint d\theta = 0$ but it is not! This is because $\theta$ is not a continuous function.

By means of distributions (generalized functions) one can make sense of the form $d\theta$ but then $d\theta$ is not an exact form, i.e. $d^2\theta \neq 0$! In fact it is not even closed! By a direct calculation it is easy to check that $d^2\theta=0$ away from $r=0$ but
$$
\int_\Delta d^2\theta = \int_{\partial \Delta} d\theta = 2\pi\Longrightarrow d^2\theta = 2\pi \delta(x-x_0)\delta(y-y_0)dxdy
$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function. Then you will see that you need to modify your usage of Stokes theorem to
$$
u(x_0, y_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\Delta ud^2\theta= \int_\Delta u(x,y)\delta(x-x_0)\delta(y-y_0)dx dy
$$
which is a trivial equation. So the correct version of your argument leads to a trivial statement $u(x_0, y_0)=u(x_0, y_0)$ at the end and does not prove anything.

Comment: Don't we only need $d \theta$ to be defined locally, though? So long as our point $x_0$ is not 0, I don't see why $d \theta$  is not a well defined differential form, at least on an appropriate neighborhood.

Comment: As long as you are integrating away from zero you are right. But when you use the stokes theorem the integration becomes over $\Delta$ and then it becomes important that $d\theta$ is not well-defined at zero.

Comment: Another issue is that if $d^2\theta$ was finite at zero, then again your locality argument would work but it is not! In fact $d^2\theta$ has a Dirac sigularity at zero.

Comment: I am still confused as to why an appropriate choice of $\Delta$ does not obviate the issue. $\Delta$ here is a subset of $R^2 - {0}$, a domain on which $d\theta$ is smooth, and hence free from singularities.

Comment: Yes you can choose a neighborhood $\Delta\subset \mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ on which $d\theta$ is smooth. But then this neighborhood by definition doesn't contain $0$! Then how are you supposed to use $u(0)=\int_\Delta ud\theta$ if $0\notin \Delta$? The point is if $\theta$ is measured from a point $(x_0,y_0)$ and $U$ is any neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ then $d\theta$ is never well-defined everywhere on $U$ no matter what $U$ is!

Comment: We don't need to apply the result if $x_0 = 0$. We need only to apply it for non-zero $x_0$, and then recover the "result" eg. by continuity.

Or consider the case where $\Omega$ does not include the origin.

Comment: How do you define your angle $\theta$? In mean value property that  you are using $\theta$ is not measured from zero! It is measured from the point $(x_0, y_0)$, e.g. for $x-x_0=r\cos \theta$ not $x=r\cos\theta$! If you want to measure $\theta$ from zero then some $dr$ also appears in your measure of integration!